# J2EE JTA Transaction rollback not working on OSE Glassfish 4.0 (Build 89)

Tags: java, glassfish, eclipselink, ejb-3.0, jersey-2.0

I'm new to J2EE and want to use container managed transactions. My problem is when i'm shutting down the server during a long running task which should be transactional, all the data which has been already processed will be committed. What I'm doing wrong here? Shouldn't that be rolled back? It looks like the EntityManager flushes everything on server shutdown even if the function is not finished.

### Used server and technologies

- Glassfish 4.0 (Build 89)
- EclipseLink
- Jersey
- EJB

### EJB example class

```java
@Stateless
@RequestScoped
@Path("/companys")
public class CompanysResource {
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private static final Logger mLogger = LoggerFactory
            .getLogger(CompanysResource.class);

    @HeaderParam(UserSession.SESSION_NAME)
    private String mSessionId;

    @Context
    private ResourceContext mResourceContext;

    @Context
    private UriInfo mUriInfo;

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = PersistenceUtils.PERSISTENCE_UNIT)
    private EntityManager mEntityManager;
    private CompanyService mCompanyService;

    public CompanysResource() {
      ...
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void initServices() {
        mCompanyService = new CompanyService(mEntityManager);
    }

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    public Response create(CompanyDTO companyDTO) {
        UserSession userSession = UserSessionService
                .getValidUserSessionBySessionId(mEntityManager, mSessionId);
        //***************************************************
        //Long running example!
        //Server shutting down before leaving the persist function
        //***************************************************
        Company company = mCompanyService.persist(userSession, companyDTO);

        // Create URI
        UriBuilder absolutePathBuilder = mUriInfo.getAbsolutePathBuilder();
        URI createdURI = absolutePathBuilder.path(company.getId().toString())
                .build();

        return Response.created(createdURI).build();
    }
    //...
}
```

### persistence.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="1.0"
             xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="ILVPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <!-- Tomcat Datasource -->
    <!--  <non-jta-data-source>java:/comp/env/jdbc/prego_ilvDS</non-jta-data-source> -->
    <!-- <jta-data-source>java:/comp/env/jdbc/prego_ilvDS</jta-data-source> -->

    <!-- Glassfish Datasource -->
    <!-- <non-jta-data-source>jdbc/prego_ilvDS</non-jta-data-source> -->
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/prego_ilvDS</jta-data-source>

    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
      <!-- Shared Cache Enable/Disable -->
      <property name="eclipselink.cache.shared.default" value="false"/>

      <!--  Statement caching -->
      <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.cache-statements" value="true" />
      <!-- Batch writing -->
      <!--
      <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.batch-writing" value="JDBC" />
      <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.batch-writing.size" value="1000" />
      -->

      <!--  Close EntityManager on commit, to avoid cost of resume -->
      <!-- <property name="eclipselink.persistence-context.close-on-commit" value="true" /> -->

      <!--  Avoid auto flush cost on query execution -->
      <!--
      <property name="eclipselink.persistence-context.flush-mode" value="commit" />

      <property name="eclipselink.persistence-context.reference-mode" value="WEAK"/>
      -->

      <!--  Avoid cost of persist on commit -->
      <!-- <property name="eclipselink.persistence-context.persist-on-commit" value="false" /> -->

      <!-- EclipseLink JPA Debug Logging -->
      <!-- Turn Logging Off -->
      <!-- <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="off" /> -->
      <property name="javax.persistence.logging.level" value="INFO"/>
      <!-- -->
      <property name="eclipselink.logging.level.sql" value="FINE"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.logging.parameters" value="true"/>
      <!-- -->
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you annotated your service method with @Transactional annotation. Without it the database operations inside are not executed in one transaction and autocommit is used. 
You can also use @Transactional annotation on your class. It's the same as putting it on each method. 
Hope it helps.

Comment: I've tried `@Transactional`, `@TransactionManagement` and `@TransactionAttribute` but nothing changed the behaviour. The transaction works correct if I throw an RuntimeException even without `@Transactional`. I'm currently lost because i have no idea why this happens when i'm stopping the glassfish server.